# Belongs_to relationship in edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form-for

I'm encountering a problem when editing a form with a belongs_to relationship (extra_guest belongs_to age_table).

I am able to create a new extra_guest and assign it to an age_table, but I cannot get the edit/update to work as my update function returns a falseClass.--> `@extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params).errors.full_messages` returns `` undefined method `errors' for false:FalseClass ``

**Code**

models

```
class ExtraGuest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :age_table
  validates :age_table, presence: true
end

class AgeTable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :park
  has_many :extra_guests, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, :age_from, :age_to, presence: true
  validates_associated :extra_guests
end

class Attraction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :park

  has_many :extra_guests, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :extra_guests, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Park < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attractions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :age_tables, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, :currency, presence: true
end
```

extra_guests_controller

```
def edit
    @extra_guest = ExtraGuest.find(params[:id])
    @age_table = @extra_guest.age_table
    @age_table_list = AgeTable.where(park: @attraction.park)
  end

  def update
    @extra_guest = @attraction.extra_guests.find(params[:id])
    @age_table = AgeTable.find(params[:age_table])
    authorize @extra_guest
    if @extra_guest = @extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @attraction = Attraction.find(params[:attraction_id])
      @extra_guest = ExtraGuest.find(params[:id])
      @age_table_list = @attraction.park.age_tables
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

private
  def extra_guest_params
    params.require(:extra_guest).permit(:name, :age_table_id,
      extra_guest_prices_attributes: [:id, :name, :price_type, :start_date, :end_date, :price, :duration, :duration_min, :duration_max, :backend_only, :weekend_extra, :_destroy])
  end
```

views/extra_guests/form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@attraction, @extra_guest] do |f|%>
     <%= f.input :age_table, :as => :select, :selected => @age_table.id, :collection => @age_table_list.map {|u| [u.name, u.id]}, :include_blank => false %>
<% f.button :submit %>
```

**Error message + params**

```
Couldn't find AgeTable without an ID

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"l8HMnVIRybZg==",
 "extra_guest"=>
  {"age_table"=>"104",
   "extra_guest_prices_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>{"price"=>"1.0", "weekend_extra"=>"", "start_date"=>"2019-10-15", "end_date"=>"20-09-2019", "duration"=>"", "duration_min"=>"", "duration_max"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"42"},
     "1"=>{"price"=>"1.0", "weekend_extra"=>"", "start_date"=>"2019-10-15", "end_date"=>"2019-10-16", "duration"=>"", "duration_min"=>"", "duration_max"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"43"}}},
 "commit"=>"Save new option",
 "attraction_id"=>"185",
 "id"=>"55"}
```

Comment: You pass your ID in `params[:extra_guest][:age_table]`, not in `params[:age_table_id]`. BTW why are you doing this this way? You can set association id using mass assignment, along with all other attributes.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed transfers the ID properly. As for the mass assignment, I never used this before, but I will definitely look into it.

Comment: You were, actually, `@extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params)` is mass assignment. There's no reason there can't be `age_table_id` in `extra_guest_params`. This way you don't need to write code only to update `age_table_id` attribute.

Comment: Aah, I see. I updated the params, but my update(extra_guest_params) returns false. I will update the question here to reflect my current status.

Answer (score 1):

Method `update`  returns `true` or `false`. You can find docs [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#validations). To check errors you need to call method `errors` on `@extra_guest` object.

```
@extra_guest.update(extra_guest_params)
@extra_guest.errors.full_messages
```